# Getting an error with Pandas Panel boolean indexing

Tags: pandas, indexing, panel

I have a panel `stocks` which has `['volume'], ['30_Avg_Vol'] and ['20_Avg_Vol']` as axes

```
stocks.Volume
                   AAPL        OPK
Date                              
010-01-11  115557365.0   130195.0
2010-01-12  148614774.0   121245.0
2010-01-13  151472335.0    47897.0
2010-01-14  108288411.0   126539.0
2010-01-15  148584065.0   175261.0
2010-01-19  182501620.0   123318.0
2010-01-20  153037892.0   100803.0
2010-01-21  152038565.0   262285.0
2010-01-22  220441872.0   114525.0


stocks['30_Avg_Vol']
Date                AAPL           OPK
2010-01-21           NaN           NaN
2010-01-22           NaN           NaN
2010-01-25  1.526774e+08  1.607402e+05
2010-01-26  1.723086e+08  1.592968e+05
2010-01-27  1.875047e+08  1.554605e+05
2010-01-28  1.933864e+08  1.540021e+05
2010-01-29  1.996023e+08  1.549712e+05
2010-02-01  1.989956e+08  1.532240e+05

stocks['20_Avg_Vol']
                     AAPL          OPK
Date                         
2010-01-12           NaN           NaN
2010-01-13           NaN           NaN
2010-01-14           NaN           NaN
2010-01-15  1.315716e+08  1.718937e+05
2010-01-19  1.362016e+08  1.674777e+05
2010-01-20  1.376046e+08  1.619215e+05
2010-01-21  1.387149e+08  1.696418e+05
2010-01-22  1.445526e+08  1.657049e+05
2010-01-25  1.526774e+08  1.607402e+05
2010-01-26  1.723086e+08  1.592968e+05
2010-01-27  1.875047e+08  1.554605e+05
```

I'm trying to slice the panel in the following way

```
 stocks[(stocks['Volume']> (1.5 * stocks['30_Avg_Vol']))|(stocks['Volume']> (1.5* stocks['20_Avg_Vol']))]
```

Wherever, the Volume is greater than 1.5 times the 30day average volume or 20day average volume.

but I'm getting the following error:

```
raise ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Any way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `MultiIndex`. To index into a `MultiIndex` you have to specify your keys in pairs (or in triplets, and so on).

The easiest way to get around this is to reset to a singular index:

So:

```
stocks[(stocks['Volume']> (1.5 * stocks['30_Avg_Vol']))|(stocks['Volume']> (1.5* stocks['20_Avg_Vol']))]
```

Becomes:

```
_stocks = stocks.reset_index()

_stocks[(_stocks['Volume']> (1.5 * _stocks['30_Avg_Vol']))|(_stocks['Volume']> (1.5* _stocks['20_Avg_Vol']))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't test out the code yet but will reply once I do. =)

Comment: So when I run this code : `_stocks = stocks.reset_index()`  I get the following error:    `AttributeError: 'Panel' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

The underscore if front of stocks, what exactly does that do?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you're using panels; sorry, I missed that in your summary. If this didn't work than I actually recommend moving *away* from doing what you're doing in `pandas`, because `pandas` `Panel` objects are deprecated and IIRC will be removed entirely in the next major version (`0.20.0`). Instead, use [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), which was designed to replace `pandas.Panel`. cf. http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html. This isn't directly an answer to your question though unfortunately...

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize they would removed entirely.  I will look into xarray.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI I was wrong, they're only being deprecated in the next version. =) Thought they were already deprecated...see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15601